# Why is my program not showing any output? 0 errors, 0 warnings but no output? I'm using Dev C++ compiler

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};
void CountNodes(struct node *head);
```

Is this declaration correct? I really don't understand why it's not showing output.

```
int main()
{
    struct node *head=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->data=45;
    struct node *current=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current->data=90;
    head->link=current;
    struct node *next=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    next->data=100;
    current->link=next;
    CountNodes(head);
}
void CountNodes(struct node *head)
```

Even this function is accurate. It was working just 10 min ago but now it's not.

```
{
    int count=0;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
    printf("Linked list is empty!");
    }
    struct node *ptr=NULL;
    ptr=head;
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        count++;
        ptr=ptr->link;
    }`enter code here`
    printf("%d",count);
}
```

Comment: In the first line it's showing that I haven't closed brackets for the <stdlib.h> header file. I've closed it properly in my program. Ignore that, please.

Comment: `next->link` is not initialized to point to neither a properly allocated `node` instance, nor `NULL`.

Comment: To extend goodvibration's comment, since you haven't supplied a value for `next->link`, it's possible that your linked list contains a cycle and your program never ends. It's also possible, and more likely, that it crashes and you're not watching `stderr`? Anyway, setting the `link` should resolve the problem.

Comment: Why is my program not showing any output? 0 errors, 0 warnings but no output?  You understand that's normal, right?  Once you get '0 errors, 0 warnings', then you have to start work - the testing and debugging starts now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I have found the bug in your code.

---

```
    struct node *head=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->data=45;
    struct node *current=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current->data=90;
    head->link=current;
    struct node *next=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    next->data=100;
    current->link=next;
    CountNodes(head);
```

It is your code in main function.
Before answering the question here are some tips for you->

1. Use tab Indentation to improve the readability of code.
2. In your code when you do `current->data=90;` or assign a value to the struct then you should also assign the `link` pointer to **`NULL`** by `current->link = NULL` and this is why there is a bug in your code.

When I ran your code on my system then it ran in an infinite loop.
So the upgraded code for you program is ->

```
    struct node *head=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->data=45;
    head->link = NULL;

    struct node *current=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current->data=90;
    current->link = NULL;
    head->link=current;

    struct node *next=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    next->data=100;
    current->link=next;
    next->link = NULL;

    CountNodes(head);
```

In the above code after each assigning of value , I'm assign the link pointer to `NULL` which is a good practice and the bug was this too.

```
struct node *next=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
next->data=100;
current->link=next;
CountNodes(head);
```

Here above you have not initialized `next` pointer with anything. So it is containing some Garbage Address and this running a loop that never ends.